# Why are tuples not destructured when iterating over an array of tuples?

Tags: rust

When iterating over an array of tuples, why does Rust not destructure the tuples? For example:

```
let x: &[(usize, usize)] = &[...];

for (a,b) in x.iter() {
    ...
}
```

leads to the error:

```
error: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, (usize, usize)> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == (_, _)`:
expected &-ptr,
found tuple [E0271]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern `(a, b)` is a tuple of type `(usize, usize)`, while your iterator returns references to tuples (i.e. `&(usize, usize)`), so the typechecker rightly complains.

You can solve this by adding an `&` in your pattern, like this:

```
for &(a,b) in x.iter() {
```